# Cannot Properly Escape Inline JS From JSON Template

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

Here is a snippet from part of my JSON template where I am struggling to properly escape some inline JS:

```
"output" : "...
            <a data-bind=\"attr: { href: '/click?url=' + 
            encodeURIComponent(imageLnk())
            .replace(/'/g,\"%27\")
            .replace(/"/g,\"%22\"), 
            onclick: 'return sl(this,\\'nw\\',\\'' + $root.moduleId() + '_i' + 
            $data.index() + '-1\\');' }\">
                <img data-bind=\"attr: { src: imageSrc, alt: imageAlt }\">
            </a>
            ..."
```

Ignore my whitespace. I added it for legibility.

My issue is with escaping the quotes (`'` and `"`) within the `.replace(/'/g,\"%27\").replace(/"/g,\"%22\")` part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one had the guts to wade through the mucky swamp that is my JSON (and who can honestly blame anyone for not wanting to?), I decided to circumvent my issue by attaching a function to my model called `encodeLink` which simply returns the inline knockout JS posted above. However, I would still love to know how the above code should be properly escaped (if it's possible)!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to create a custom binding handler (e.g. "url") and put all the escaping code in it. Right now you've got too much logic in your view; among other things, this will bite you if you have to run in an environment that implements certain content security policies (where you may have to use something like the secure-bindings plugin, which doesn't allow function calls in bindings).